# Normal user starts in ubuntu-2D look, guest session in 3d

Tags: unity, compiz

currently I'm having a kind of very strange problem. When I login as my default user, then unity, whatever I have chosen in start-up dialog, starts with ubuntu-2D. That's exactly what `echo $DESKTOP_SESSION` confirms. Also, compiz is not started. When I however decide to login via guest session, unity starts just fine in 3D-mode.

`/usr/lib/nux/unity-support-test -p` confirms that unity 3d is supported. (Yes, for each line.)

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with an ATI/AMD Radeon HD 3200 with proprietary fglrx drivers.

Problem was appearing after I updated unity and compiz. Before everything just worked fine.

What still works is starting compiz by myself, but then I have two side bars, which are overlapping and so not looking fine. I also tried to put compiz into autostart, but then starting my computer is taking much time and I'm still having that overlapping-problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you reach the logon screen to enter your password, you will see a little icon on the right hand side of your name. Click this icon, and ensure that it's set to unity and not unity-2d.

This worked for me, i have a mobile amd 5xxx series, and for some reason it switched me to unity-2d, hope this works for you.

Comment: "When I login as my default user, then unity, whatever I have chosen in start-up dialog, starts with ubuntu-2D". So I already tried that. ;)